# C programming processing va_args using sprintf?

Tags: c

I am trying to learn how va_args work, I want to merge the list of args with the format string inside of this function im making.  The way im doing it now just results in jiberish.  Is there a way that will let me avoid having to write some massive processing function?

```
va_start( listPointer, msg );
#ifdef DEBUG
fprintf(stderr, msg, listPointer);
#endif
str = (char *)calloc(sizeof(MAX_LINE_SIZE), sizeof(char));
if(str == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory exception");
    return;
}
snprintf(str, MAX_LINE_SIZE, listPointer);
printf("testing: %s\n", str);
ret = write(logger, str, strlen(str));
if(ret == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, 
            "Could not write to file with error: %s\n", 
            strerror(errno));
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot continue with error logging");
}
va_end( listPointer );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  It also helps no end if you provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  We can guess (but shouldn't have to guess) that you have `void function(const char *msg, ...) { va_list listPointer;` before your code, or something similar.  Please provide the complete function, at least.  You should be using `vsnprintf()` or one of the other members of the `v*printf()` family, I believe.

Comment: Your call to [`calloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) doesn’t do what you think it’s doing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [vsprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsprintf/) or [vsnprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsnprintf/) function.  Rather than taking a list of parameters it takes a va_list for its parameters.

You would call it as:

```
vsnprintf(str, MAX_LINE_SIZE, listPointer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write variable argument functions in pairs:

```
void ellipsis_function(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    valist_function(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

void valist_function(const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
}
```

The first function should be very close to what I showed; there might be extra fixed arguments, and maybe a return value to capture, but otherwise it really is that simple.

The second function can do whatever you need, formatting data into strings with `vsnprintf()` et al, etc.